# JPQL Query - No constructor taking error?

Tags: jpa, constructor, spring-data-jpa, jpql, qlrm

I have a Card entity class with many columns.
I used dto because I want to get some columns from this Entity.
I created a DTO class and wrote a query to CardRepositoryCustom.
But when I try to run the Query I get various errors "No constructor taking".

My dto class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CardDTO {
    private String test1;
    private String test2;
    private String test3;
    private String test4;
}
```

JPQL RepositoryCustom :

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CardRepositoryCustom {

    public CardDTO test1() {
        JpaResultMapper jpaResultMapper = new JpaResultMapper();
        String q =  "SELECT          "+
                    "   c.test1  "+
                    "FROM            "+
                    "   CardEntity c ";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(q);
        try {
            return jpaResultMapper.uniqueResult(query, CardDTO.class);
        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No constructor taking: java.lang.String
at org.qlrm.mapper.JpaResultMapper.findConstructor(JpaResultMapper.java:107) ~[qlrm-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.qlrm.mapper.JpaResultMapper.uniqueResult(JpaResultMapper.java:64) ~[qlrm-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at ....
```

I know how to fix this error.
You just need to write the following constructor in the DTO class as shown below.

```
public CardDTO(String test1) {
    this.setTest1(test1);       
}
```

Here I am curious, if I want test2, test3, test4 and write Query in Custom class, should there be as many constructors in DTO class as that number?

I think this method is really inefficient. Is there any solution I am not aware of?

Comment: What exactly is inefficient about having four parameters, when you want to take four arguments?

Comment: When I SELECT test1, test2, test3, test4, don't the numbers in various cases such as 1,2 or 3,4 or 1,4 come out? If that's the case, I think that the constructor has to be written that much too, which makes the code too messy.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to handle these various constructors like lombok's 
annotation getter and setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be more about [QLRM](https://github.com/72services/qlrm) than JPA or Spring.

Judging from the error message the constructor has to match the arguments provided. Probably the easiest variant is to always provide all arguments, possibly with a value of `null` or some other literal.
The query in your example would then become.

```
SELECT c.test1, null, null, null FROM CardEntity c
```

Of course QLRM just provides a `JpaResultMapper` and it would probably not too difficult to provide your own, or offer a PR to QLRM that inspects names of the result set and tries to match them to parameter names or the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a question.

You mentioned that QLRM is used more often. I mainly used QLRM for aggregate queries and complex JOIN queries. If so, can you tell me that the project I created uses JPA?

Comment: Should I have used a method like findBytest1() to configure the project using JPA?